# Transit Visa disembarking from cruise ship?

Tags: visas, transit, uk-citizens, oman, muscat

I will be disembarking off a cruise ship in Muscat then flying back to the UK on a British passport the same day do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Ask your cruise line. For one day it could not be necessary. Cruise line often get good deals (check and visa done on board by cruise line, controlled transfer to airport, etc.Sometime they tests new simplified immigration procedures). Oman is trying to improve tourism

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [British nationals need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/oman/entry-requirements) to enter Oman. You can apply for an e-visa via https://evisa.rop.gov.om/

Comment: @BritishSam I included the Gov.uk link rather than the direct link to the Omani visa website because the former also provides additional valuable information eg passport validity and travelling with medication. The latter being particularly important in this region of the world.

Comment: Note: http://www.rop.gov.om/old/english/dg_pr_visas_shipcrew.asp  Visa free for one day, but I'm not sure that disembarkation day is considered as "stop". Usually on stop you get a pink card (a sort of authorization document) (that you should give back when you go back to the ship). Possibly the airport could also collect it.

Comment: @Traveller I feel links to both would be better, I know the .gov link links to the eVisa page too